# How to get different layouts using the same pinescript indicator to use the latest version?

Tags: pine-script

I have a few layouts that use the same indicator that I wrote in pinescript but they're using different versions of the same indicator. How do I automatically make the different layouts use the latest version?

I am using pinescript v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you'll have to go through each layout one-by-one, removing the old indicator version, and manually add the newer version.

Even with dozens of layouts and numerous indicator settings to manage this shouldn't take you too long! :)